# PyCharm 2022.2 is stuck on the splash screen

Tags: pycharm

Whenever I try to open PyCharm 2022.2, I get stuck on the splash screen. Quitting and reopening the app doesn't help. I'm using macOS 12.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I've had plugins that needed to be updated. After that, I restarted PyCharm and it loaded up correctly.

These are the new versions of the plugins, try to update them if you have these:

- CSV (2.19.0)
- ExcelReader (2022.2.2)
- Material Theme UI (7.7.1)
- Rainbow CSV (2.0.2)